# How to determine if clicked position in an element has text

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to detect whether the user is clicked on part of an element that has text or not.

In a code it could be usable like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  const clickedElement = ev.target;
  // Here I'd like to determine if clickedElement has content on the clicked position
});
```

Let's take this div as example:

`<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%">test</div>`

The div stretches to whole screen with a text inside:

- If user clicks anywhere on this div but not the text, I'd like to determine "there's no content!"
- If user clicks anywhere on text of the div, I'd like to determine "there's content!"

I'd like to determine a click of the rendered text of this element, not its children.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all your texts inside a `span` element with a class and then detect the click easily.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').off("click", "#container");
    $('body').on("click", "#container", function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('text')) {
            alert('you clicked on a text');
        }
        else {
            alert('there is no content!');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; background:yellow">
<span class="text"> test </span>
<span class="text"> asd </span>
<span class="text"> zxc </span>
<span class="text"> zxcvvv </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a span tag, between **test**, like this

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%"><span class="text">test</span></div>
```

So you can ask if text class is included in target className, like this

```
document.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  const clickedElement = ev.target;
  if (ev.target.className.includes("text") {
    // TODO
  }
})
```